# c code reports undef sprintf in dumpbin Compiles no error

Tags: c

I have c code that compiles and links fine on another PC. I am tring now to get everything to work on my Windows 7 64 bit OS. The Code compiles into a object with no errors however when I run dumpbin on the object with `/SYMBOLS` I get several `UNDEF` messages.

```
0F9 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__sprintf
0FA 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__fclose
0FB 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__fopen
0FC 00000008 SECT3  notype       Static       | _i
0FD 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _strcmp
0FE 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__setlocale
0FF 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _strcpy
100 00000290 SECT5  notype ()    Static       | _f_read_common_fields
101 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _memcpy
102 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__fread
103 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _memset
104 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | ___security_cookie
105 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | @__security_check_cookie@4
```

Seems like I am just message a path statement or something but can not find it. This is all external code (Not in a VS Project) using VS2005 to compile from the command line.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Why am I getting all the UNDEF messages? I am assuming this is what is causing the Linker to fail with Unresolved Symbols error.

Comment: What files did you `#include`? What is the command used to compile?

Comment: Include:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
/* header files for WinExec */
#include <direct.h>
#include <windows.h>
/* header file for Extended precision & struct ief_globdata */
#include <tiabinc.h>

Comment: Command: cl -c -W3 -MD -D_AFXDLL -nologo -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_DLL -Fo TTEC020E.c

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a linker problem.  I see your compile line, but what about the link line.  Off the top of my head I can't remember the VC library for standard c stuff.

Is it msvcrt.lib?  Are you including that on the link line?

Comment: This is the Link Command: link /NOLOGO  /OPT:NOREF  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB  /OUT:"C:\Gen\Models\ECAPNEW.ief\c\EC020S.EXE" "C:\Gen\Models\ECAPNEW.ief\c\EC020S.RSP" @"C:\Gen\Models\ECAPNEW.ief\c\EC020S.LNK"

Result:
C:\Gen\Models\ECAPNEW.ief\c\EC020S.EXE : fatal error LNK1120: 30 unresolved externals

Comment: Have you tried taking out /NODEFAULTLIB:   ? Also, try adding  /NODEFAULTLIB:"msvcrt.lib"

Comment: Looking at some of the defines on the cl line, you are doing an MFC and multi threaded DLL?  google for what libraries you need for those build options.